# Use JRuby 9K on Travis CI

Tags: rvm, jruby, travis-ci

I've updated the [Travis configuration of one of my gems](https://github.com/fny/xorcist/blob/master/.travis.yml) to include `jruby-9.0.0.0` instead of `jruby-9.0.0.0.rc2`, but it looks like [Travis is still using `jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1`](https://travis-ci.org/fny/xorcist/jobs/76816742). Is there anything I can do to force Travis to use the production 9K release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding the following script, to get rvm head installed :

```
'if [[ "$TRAVIS_RUBY_VERSION" =~ "jruby" ]]; then rvm get head && rvm reload && rvm use --install $TRAVIS_RUBY_VERSION; fi'
```

... then **rvm: jruby-9.0.0.0** should work

Comment: Beautiful. I ended up running this during the [before_install](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#The-Build-Lifecycle) callback.